# splitting data frames in R

Tags: r, split

In spite of reading multiple answers on how to split data frame, I am unable to work out the logic.

```
df <- data.frame(x = round(rnorm(200)+5), y = round(rnorm(200)) + 10)  
spliter <- sample(nrow(df),100)  
keepData <- df[spliter,]  
leaveData <- df[!spliter,]
```

I get the keepData part okay but the leaveData object returns 0 obs where as I was expecting the balance 100 observations in the leaveData object.

Guidance on the logic will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean `df[-spliter,]`? `!spliter` convert all indices to `FALSE` since they are not zero.